# set select2 4.0 with jquery .text without using id

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4

I will be pulling values from a table, and the select2 will be populated with ajax in a form. I will not have the ID numbers (although the ID numbers could be searchable). How do I either find the ID numbers that select2 is initialized with, or set the select2 using the .text only value without using .val?s

select2 will set the value like this;

```
$('#nwco').val('2');
```

select2 will not select2 will set the value like this;

```
$('#nwco').text('Item 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Save the select2 values inside a hidden element also and then get values from that hidden element. Note that if you change anything on select2 update the hidden element also. I think this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: if I had the value to save to a hidden element I would not need the hidden element because I could set it with the value. each option in the select 2 would be the equivalent of the following; `<option value="2">Item 1</option>'`. I do not have the value, only the text, in the example "Item 1".